# How to find a set of documents by specific field(s) of similar value in mongoose / mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to see if there are some duplicate documents in a collection, so that I can delete or merge similar records.

Suppose no target values are provided, but only the target field(s), all I have to do is to find all the similar documents based on the target field(s).

For example, my collection `persons` contains the following documents:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    email: "foo@bar.com",
    name: "tom",
    phone: 320513218,
    company: {
        name: "Bar"
        department: "Marketing"
    }
},{
    _id: 2,
    email: "foo@bar.com",
    name: "alex c",
    phone: 7320320813,
    company: {
        name: "Bar"
        department: "Development"
    }
},{
    _id: 3,
    email: "not_foo@not_bar.com",
    name: "alex w",
    phone: 895120981,
    company: {
        name: "Not Bar"
        department: "Development"
    }
},{
    _id: 4,
    email: "not_foo@not_bar.com",
    name: "emily",
    phone: 895120981,
    company: {
        name: "Another Company"
        department: "Marketing"
    }
},{
    _id: 5,
    email: "foo@bar.com",
    name: "emily",
    phone: 7320320813,
    company: {
        name: "Another Company"
        department: "Marketing"
    }
},...
```

1. I would like to find duplicate documents based on `email` first, I should get `[{_id: 1, count: 3}, {_id: 2, count: 3}, {_id: 5, count: 3}, {_id: 3, count: 2}, {_id: 4, count: 2}]` as the result. (Don't worry about the order of array)
2. Then, I would like to find duplicate documents based on `phone`, I should get `[{_id: 2, count: 2}, {_id: 5, count: 2}, {_id: 3, count: 2}, {_id: 4, count: 2}]` as the result. (Don't worry about the order of array)
3. Then, I would like to find duplicate documents based on `name`, I should get`[{_id: 2, count: 2}, {_id: 3, count: 2}, {_id: 4, count: 2}, {_id: 5, count: 2}]` as the result.
4. Lastly, I would like to find duplicate documents based on both `email` and `phone`, I should get`[{_id: 2, count: 2}, {_id: 5, count: 2}]` as the result.

(`count` should be the number of duplicate records (self included))

I have tried both `mapReduce` and `aggregate` methods provided by mongo/mongoose, but they couldn't fulfill my expectations.

I want something like "group and count by multiple (similar) fields"

Please tell me if you need more information, such as my current sample code.

Answer (score 1):

You need a separate aggregation for each duplicate search. In all cases, just group on whatever the (possibly compound) key is that defines a duplicate, then push the `_id`'s to an array and count the number of results:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { "$group" : { "_id" : KEY, "ids" : { "$push" : "$_id" }, "count" : { "$sum" : 1 } } }
])
```

For example, for `phone`:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { "$group" : { "_id" : "$phone", "ids" : { "$push" : "$_id" }, "count" : { "$sum" : 1 } } }
])
```

For `email` and `phone`:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { "$group" : { "_id" : { "phone" : "$phone", "email" : "$email" }, "ids" : { "$push" : "$_id" }, "count" : { "$sum" : 1 } } }
])
```

This gives output that's different than what you requested, for example for your sample docs and `phone` you get

```
{ "_id" : 895120981, "ids" : [3, 4], "count" : 2 },
{ "_id" : 7320320813, "ids" : [2, 5], "count" : 2 },
{ "_id" : 320513218, "ids" : [1], "count" : 1 }
```

But it's got the same information and is a simpler (faster) aggregation.

To filter out unique values, append a `$match` stage:

```
{ "$match" : { "count" : { "$gt" : 1 } } }
```

Comment: thank you for the advice. I think it may work for the exactly same values, but can I group by similar values of specific field(s)? such as `{_id: 2}, {_id: 3}`, they are both named `alex`, but different middle-name or last-name.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Question 1.

```
db.test.aggregate(
{ $group: 
        { _id : 
            {email : '$email'},  
                id : {$push :"$_id"},
                count : {$sum:1}        
        }
},
{$unwind:"$id"},
{$group: 
        {_id: 
            {_id:"$id",count:"$count"},

            }
     }
)
```

Comment: Why do you need the second `$group`?

Comment: i actually wanted to slice the output to get only the _id and count. somehow couldnt slice, hence used group.